# JUnit test for System.out.println()

Tags: java, console, junit

I need to write JUnit tests for an old application that's poorly designed and is writing a lot of error messages to standard output. When the `getResponse(String request)` method behaves correctly it returns a XML response:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    Properties queries = loadPropertiesFile("requests.properties");
    Properties responses = loadPropertiesFile("responses.properties");
    instance = new ResponseGenerator(queries, responses);
}

@Test
public void testGetResponse() {
    String request = "<some>request</some>";
    String expResult = "<some>response</some>";
    String result = instance.getResponse(request);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
}
```

But when it gets malformed XML or does not understand the request it returns `null` and writes some  stuff to standard output.

Is there any way to assert console output in JUnit? To catch cases like:

```
System.out.println("match found: " + strExpr);
System.out.println("xml not well formed: " + e.getMessage());
```

Comment: Related to, but not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381801/how-do-i-unit-test-saving-file-to-the-disk

Answer (score 701, accepted):

using [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) and System.setXXX is simple:

```
private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
private final ByteArrayOutputStream errContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
private final PrintStream originalOut = System.out;
private final PrintStream originalErr = System.err;

@Before
public void setUpStreams() {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent));
}

@After
public void restoreStreams() {
    System.setOut(originalOut);
    System.setErr(originalErr);
}
```

sample test cases:

```
@Test
public void out() {
    System.out.print("hello");
    assertEquals("hello", outContent.toString());
}

@Test
public void err() {
    System.err.print("hello again");
    assertEquals("hello again", errContent.toString());
}
```

I used this code to test the command line option (asserting that -version outputs the version string, etc etc)

**Edit:**
Prior versions of this answer called `System.setOut(null)` after the tests; This is the cause of NullPointerExceptions commenters refer to.

Comment: Furthemore, I have used JUnitMatchers to test for responses:

assertThat(result, containsString("<request:GetEmployeeByKeyResponse"));

Thanks, dfa.

Comment: I prefer to use System.setOut(null) to restore the stream back to what it was when the VM was launched

Comment: The javadocs don't say anything about being able to pass null to System.setOut or System.setErr.  Are you sure this will work on all JREs?

Comment: I encountered a `NullPointerException` in other tests after setting a null error stream as suggested above (in `java.io.writer(Object)`, called internally by an XML validator). I would suggest instead saving the original in a field: `oldStdErr = System.err` and restoring this in the `@After` method.

Comment: I am having an issue with EclEmma with this solution. JUnit4 is working perfectly fine. But whenever I am calling outContent/errContent in a test, then the code coverage is wrongly performed and the branch is marked as "unexplored" while it obviously run through it during the test. I should add that I am also using the [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.com/system-rules/) library. If anybody already encountered this problem and got a workaround I would be happy to know more about it.

Comment: Great solution. Just a note for anyone using it, you may need to trim() whitespace/newline from outContent.

Comment: This approach is fraught with problems because the standard output stream is a shared resource used by all parts of your program. It is better to use Dependency Injection to eliminate the direct use of the standard output stream:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21216342/545127

Comment: at the moment that seems to be the signle option to get it work with Junit 5 (doesn't have @Rules anymore)

Comment: `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` for JUnit5.

Comment: @Line you might want to use BeforeEach and AfterEach if only some of your tests use System.out.println

Comment: @Sebastien wouldn't it work the same way as `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll`? if only some of the tests need that, wouldn't it be better to put the redirection in the specific tests body? then it wouldn't affect the other tests

Comment: @Line you are right, I must have skipped my coffee that morning.

Answer (score 108):

I know this is an old thread, but there is a nice library to do this: [System Rules](https://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules)
Example from the docs:

```java
public void MyTest {
    @Rule
    public final SystemOutRule systemOutRule = new SystemOutRule().enableLog();

    @Test
    public void overrideProperty() {
        System.out.print("hello world");
        assertEquals("hello world", systemOutRule.getLog());
    }
}
```

It will also allow you to trap `System.exit(-1)` and other things that a command line tool would need to be tested for.

Comment: This approach is fraught with problems because the standard output stream is a shared resource used by all parts of your program. It is better to use Dependency Injection to eliminate the direct use of the standard output stream:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21216342/545127

Answer (score 42):

Instead of redirecting `System.out`, I would refactor the class that uses `System.out.println()` by passing a `PrintStream` as a collaborator and then using `System.out` in production and a *Test Spy* in the test.  That is, use Dependency Injection to eliminate the direct use of the standard output stream.

**In Production**

```
ConsoleWriter writer = new ConsoleWriter(System.out));
```

**In the Test**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outSpy = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ConsoleWriter writer = new ConsoleWriter(new PrintStream(outSpy));
writer.printSomething();
assertThat(outSpy.toString(), is("expected output"));
```

**Discussion**

This way the class under test becomes testable by a simple refactoring, without having the need for indirect redirection of the standard output or obscure interception with a system rule.

Comment: I could not find this ConsoleWriter anywhere in the JDK: where is it ?

Comment: It should probably be mentioned in the answer, but I believe that class was created by user1909402.

Comment: I think `ConsoleWriter` is the test subject,

Comment: you wont find a simple consolewrite class in the jdk, but it should be really trivial to implement

Comment: This is probably the most _correct_ answer, but keep in mind if you can't refactor the test subject to do this for any reason, the accepted answer is the solution.

Answer (score 22):

You can set the System.out print stream via [setOut()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29) (and for `in` and `err`). Can you redirect this to a print stream that records to a string, and then inspect that ? That would appear to be the simplest mechanism.

(I would advocate, at some stage, convert the app to some logging framework - but I suspect you already are aware of this!)

Comment: That was something that came to my mind but I couldn't believe there is no standard JUnit way to do that. Thanks, Brain. But the credits got to dfa for the actual effort.

Comment: This approach is fraught with problems because the standard output stream is a shared resource used by all parts of your program. It is better to use Dependency Injection to eliminate the direct use of the standard output stream:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21216342/545127

Comment: Yes. I would second that and perhaps even question a logging assert (better to assert a call onto a logging component or similar)

Answer (score 13):

Slightly off topic, but in case some people (like me, when I first found this thread) might be interested in capturing log output via SLF4J, [commons-testing](https://github.com/marccarre/commons-testing)'s JUnit `@Rule` might help:

```
public class FooTest {
    @Rule
    public final ExpectedLogs logs = new ExpectedLogs() {{
        captureFor(Foo.class, LogLevel.WARN);
    }};

    @Test
    public void barShouldLogWarning() {
        assertThat(logs.isEmpty(), is(true)); // Nothing captured yet.

        // Logic using the class you are capturing logs for:
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        assertThat(foo.bar(), is(not(nullValue())));

        // Assert content of the captured logs:
        assertThat(logs.isEmpty(), is(false));
        assertThat(logs.contains("Your warning message here"), is(true));
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer**:

- I developed this library since I could not find any suitable solution for my own needs.
- Only bindings for `log4j`, `log4j2` and `logback` are available at the moment, but I am happy to add more.

Comment: Thank you so much for creating this library! I have been looking for something like this for such a long time! It's very, very useful as sometimes you simply cannot simplify your code enough to be easily testable, but with a log message you can do wonders!

Comment: This looks really promising... but even when I just copy your ATMTest program and run it as a test under Gradle, I'm getting an exception... I've raised an issue on your Github page...

Answer (score 12):

If you were using Spring Boot (you mentioned that you're working with an old application, so you probably aren't but it might be of use to others), then you could use **org.springframework.boot.test.rule.OutputCapture** in the following manner:

```
@Rule
public OutputCapture outputCapture = new OutputCapture();

@Test
public void out() {
    System.out.print("hello");
    assertEquals(outputCapture.toString(), "hello");
}
```

Comment: I up-voted your answer because I use Spring boot and it set me on the right track. Thanks! However, outputCapture needs to be initialized. (public OutputCapture outputCapture = new OutputCapture();) See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-output-capture-test-utility

Answer (score 9):

@dfa answer is great, so I took it a step farther to make it possible to test blocks of ouput.

First I created `TestHelper` with a method `captureOutput` that accepts the annoymous class `CaptureTest`. The captureOutput method does the work of setting and tearing down the output streams. When the implementation of `CaptureOutput`'s `test` method is called, it has access to the output generate for the test block.

Source for TestHelper:

```
public class TestHelper {

    public static void captureOutput( CaptureTest test ) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream errContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent));

        test.test( outContent, errContent );

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)));
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)));

    }
}

abstract class CaptureTest {
    public abstract void test( ByteArrayOutputStream outContent, ByteArrayOutputStream errContent ) throws Exception;
}
```

Note that TestHelper and CaptureTest are defined in the same file.

Then in your test, you can import the static captureOutput. Here is an example using JUnit:

```
// imports for junit
import static package.to.TestHelper.*;

public class SimpleTest {

    @Test
    public void testOutput() throws Exception {

        captureOutput( new CaptureTest() {
            @Override
            public void test(ByteArrayOutputStream outContent, ByteArrayOutputStream errContent) throws Exception {

                // code that writes to System.out

                assertEquals( "the expected output\n", outContent.toString() );
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: i tried this helper but the result still failed, even the expected output & actual output same. Possible due to EOL or whitespace, but not sure how to prevent that.

Answer (score 8):

Based on [@dfa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1119559/1657502) and [another answer that shows how to test System.in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1648989/1657502), I would like to share my solution to give an input to a program and test its output.

As a reference, I use JUnit 4.12.

Let's say we have this program that simply replicates input to output:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(scanner.next());
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

To test it, we can use the following class:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.*;

import org.junit.*;

public class SimpleProgramTest {
    private final InputStream systemIn = System.in;
    private final PrintStream systemOut = System.out;

    private ByteArrayInputStream testIn;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream testOut;

    @Before
    public void setUpOutput() {
        testOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(testOut));
    }

    private void provideInput(String data) {
        testIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
        System.setIn(testIn);
    }

    private String getOutput() {
        return testOut.toString();
    }

    @After
    public void restoreSystemInputOutput() {
        System.setIn(systemIn);
        System.setOut(systemOut);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCase1() {
        final String testString = "Hello!";
        provideInput(testString);

        SimpleProgram.main(new String[0]);

        assertEquals(testString, getOutput());
    }
}
```

I won't explain much, because I believe the code is readable and I cited my sources.

When JUnit runs `testCase1()`, it is going to call the helper methods in the order they appear:

1. `setUpOutput()`, because of the `@Before` annotation
2. `provideInput(String data)`, called from `testCase1()`
3. `getOutput()`, called from `testCase1()`
4. `restoreSystemInputOutput()`, because of the `@After` annotation

I didn't test `System.err` because I didn't need it, but it should be easy to implement, similar to testing `System.out`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using JUnit 5 with the Jupiter API, I highly recommend trying the [junit-pioneer](https://junit-pioneer.org) library. It provides a robust solution for reading from the standard input (`System.in`) and writing to the standard output (`System.out` and `System.err`). For example, you can use it as follows:

```java
@Test
@StdIo
void out(StdOut out) {
    System.out.print("hello");
    assertEquals("hello", out.capturedLines()[0]);
}

@Test
@StdIo
public void err(StdErr err) {
    System.err.print("hello again");
    assertEquals("hello again", err.capturedLines()[0]);
}
```

In this case, there is no need to manually redefine `System.out` and `System.err`. Moreover, using `StdIo`, `StdOut`, `StdIn` can help avoid potential concurrency problems when running tests in parallel.
You can find more information about other use cases in the [official docs](https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/standard-input-output/).

The dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit-pioneer</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-pioneer</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

- You can check the latest version of the dependency [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit-pioneer/junit-pioneer).
- The `junit-pioneer` GitHub repository is right [here](https://github.com/junit-pioneer/junit-pioneer).

Answer (score 2):

Full JUnit 5 example to test `System.out` (replace the when part):

```
package learning;

import static org.assertj.core.api.BDDAssertions.then;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class SystemOutLT {

    private PrintStream originalSystemOut;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream systemOutContent;

    @BeforeEach
    void redirectSystemOutStream() {

        originalSystemOut = System.out;

        // given
        systemOutContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(systemOutContent));
    }

    @AfterEach
    void restoreSystemOutStream() {
        System.setOut(originalSystemOut);
    }

    @Test
    void shouldPrintToSystemOut() {

        // when
        System.out.println("example");

        then(systemOutContent.toString()).containsIgnoringCase("example");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for out

```
@Test
void it_prints_out() {

    PrintStream save_out=System.out;final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));

    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    assertEquals("Hello World!\r\n", out.toString());

    System.setOut(save_out);
}
```

for err

```
@Test
void it_prints_err() {

    PrintStream save_err=System.err;final ByteArrayOutputStream err= new ByteArrayOutputStream();System.setErr(new PrintStream(err));

    System.err.println("Hello World!");
    assertEquals("Hello World!\r\n", err.toString());

    System.setErr(save_err);
}
```

Comment: For this sort of setup and teardown logic I would use an `@Rule`, rather than do it inline in your test. Notably, if your assertion fails the second `System.setOut/Err` call will *not* be reached.

Answer (score 1):

If the function is printing to System.out, you can capture that output by using the System.setOut method to change System.out to go to a PrintStream provided by you. If you create a PrintStream connected to a ByteArrayOutputStream, then you can capture the output as a String.

```
// Create a stream to hold the output
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
// IMPORTANT: Save the old System.out!
PrintStream old = System.out;
// Tell Java to use your special stream
System.setOut(ps);
// Print some output: goes to your special stream
System.out.println("Foofoofoo!");
// Put things back
System.out.flush();
System.setOut(old);
// Show what happened
System.out.println("Here: " + baos.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to redirect the system.out stream because that redirects for the ENTIRE JVM. Anything else running on the JVM can get messed up. There are better ways to test input/output. Look into stubs/mocks.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is very old and has already very good answers I want to provide an alternative. I liked the answer of `dfa` however I wanted to have something reusable in different projects without copying the configuration and so I created a library out of it and wanted to contribute back to the community. It is called [Console Captor](https://github.com/Hakky54/console-captor) and you can add it with the following snippet:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.hakky54</groupId>
    <artifactId>consolecaptor</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Example class**

```java
public class FooService {

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Keyboard not responding. Press any key to continue...");
        System.err.println("Congratulations, you are pregnant!");
    }

}
```

**Unit test**

```java
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import nl.altindag.console.ConsoleCaptor;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class FooServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void captureStandardAndErrorOutput() {
        ConsoleCaptor consoleCaptor = new ConsoleCaptor();

        FooService fooService = new FooService();
        fooService.sayHello();

        assertThat(consoleCaptor.getStandardOutput()).contains("Keyboard not responding. Press any key to continue...");
        assertThat(consoleCaptor.getErrorOutput()).contains("Congratulations, you are pregnant!");
        
        consoleCaptor.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot directly print by using **system.out.println** or using **logger api** while using **JUnit**. But if you want to check any values then you simply can use

```
Assert.assertEquals("value", str);
```

It will throw below assertion error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [21.92] but found [value]
```

Your value should be 21.92, Now if you will test using this value like below your test case will pass.

```
 Assert.assertEquals(21.92, str);
```