# basics of CLI automation

Tags: java, automation, command-line-interface

I want to know any basic program (using java) for CLI automation

Comment: what do you mean by CLI automation?

Comment: @JanHrcek Please stop adding this tag just because someone used it in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try ExpectJ

http://expectj.sourceforge.net/

(I think what you're looking for is generally known as 'Expect' in several languages)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Java Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) to write your own basic program.

Alternative you can wsimulate System.in, check this thread: [JUnit: How to simulate System.in testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647907/junit-how-to-simulate-system-in-testing)