# Android: Keyboard input in Unit Test

Tags: java, android, junit

I want to implement user interaction in my Unit tests, i want user to input some info that i need in order to log him in the app, here's what i've written:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();
    mKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
}

@Test
public void userInteraction() {
    System.out.println("Enter Username and press Enter : ");
    mUsername = mKeyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Password and press Enter : ");
    mPassword = mKeyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Trying to login...");
}
```

What i'm getting: i see the message "Enter Username and press Enter :" and it looks line app is actually waiting for user to input it, but, for some reason app is not reacting to keyboard at all. I'm using AndroidStudio if that can help somehow.

Answer (score 2):

In this kind of situations I would reccomend you to write UI Tests (use Espresso for example with Espresso Test Recording: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/espresso-test-recorder.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your `mUsername = mKeyboard.nextLine();` is waiting for the user to enter something. 
Your problem is to simulate the user entries. 
A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066671/how-can-i-unit-test-user-input-in-java), and suggest to use something like that:

```
String data = "Users Input";
System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes()));
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Sorry, it's not, i actually need user to TYPE something, is it possible?

Comment: The idea of a unit test is to be done with any user. Because of that I'm not sure of what your trying to do.