# How to write a junit test for a scanner? (Reading a file)

Tags: java, junit

I have a method that scans a file and assigns values to an object:

```
private List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();

public void scanLocalFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
  File file = new File("input.txt");
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
  while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
      String[] fields = line.split(";");
      String name = fields[0];
      String score = fields[1];

  Customer customer = new Customer(name, score);
  customerList.add(customer);
  }
scan.close();
}
```

How do I write a junit test for a method like this? Is it possible to use the same file ("input.txt") for a unit test as well?

The file's structure:

```
John Smith;45;
Adam West;78;
```

Comment: don't hardcode the file; make sure you can pass it as a parameter to that method. then call that method with a test input file, and check the content of customerList afterwards

Comment: Here is similar question [how-to-junit-test-a-method-with-a-scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34139658/how-to-junit-test-a-method-with-a-scanner/34139879).

Comment: Or, pass in a `Reader` which you use as a parameter to the `Scanner` constructor: then you don't even have to worry about files, as you can use e.g. `StringReader`. Note, however, that if you pass in a `Reader`, you shouldn't close the `Scanner` at the end, because that will close the `Reader`; and it is bad practice for code to close a `Reader` (or `Writer` or `Input/OutputStream`) that it didn't open.

Comment: Also also: it's a bit dubious to have `customerList` as a field that you add to (what if you invoke `scanLocalFile()` twice?). Construct a new list in this method, add to it, and return the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic approach to make this code unit-testable is to not hard-code the use of the `input.txt` file.

[Stultuske suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69280407/how-to-write-a-junit-test-for-a-scanner-reading-a-file#comment122451405_69280407) passing in the `File` as a parameter to the method, in order that you can then run the method for an arbitrary file during testing.

I'd go a step further than that and say: pass in a `Reader`. `Scanner` has a constructor which accepts a `Reader`, and then you don't have to mess around with files during you unit test.

For example, you can construct a [`StringReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/StringReader.html) with a hard-coded string that is the "file contents".

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader("John Smith;45;\nAdam West;78;");
```

Note, however, that if you pass in a `Reader`, you shouldn't close the `Scanner` at the end, because that will close the `Reader`; and it is bad practice for code to close a `Reader` (or `Writer` or `Input/OutputStream`; generally any resource) that it didn't open.

```
public void scanLocalFile(Reader r) {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(r);
  while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
     // ...
  }
}
```

---

Actually, since you're just reading lines from the Scanner, I think it would be better to use `BufferedReader` instead:

```
public void scanLocalFile(Reader r) {
  new BufferedReader(r).lines()
      .map(line -> {
        String[] fields = line.split(";");
        return new Customer(fields[0], fields[1]);
      })
      .forEach(customerList::add);
}
```