# JUnit tests for Scanner

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to build JUnit tests for the following code:

```java
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Console {
    
    static Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        readIntegerFromStdin ();
    }
    
    public static void readIntegerFromStdin () {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter number here: ");
            int a=sc1.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Enter number here: ");
            sc2.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, I don't know how to use the input from the `Scanner` in the test. How do I get access to the Scanner's input?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock System.in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647907/junit-how-to-simulate-system-in-testing)

Comment: Why is there a need to have 2 instances of Scanner: sc1 and sc2? `readIntegerFromStdin` is not returning the Integer supposedly read from the System.in, what assertion are we planning to do? Also if the second "Enter number here: " prompt still didn't get Integer as input, what is the expectation?

Comment: @Jayr I have to create this two scanner objects because the input from the console is stored in scanners. If I use the first scanner twice than in the catch it returned automatically stored value

Comment: @AndreiKovrov not really, I started with programming now this means I am an Amateur - thats all new for me

Comment: If you write the JUNIT in the same package, assuming that you do not need to be run the test using Mockito or other testing libraries, you can write something like this: 
`public class ConsoleTest {
 @org.junit.Test
 public void main() {
  try {
   Console.sc1 = new java.util.Scanner(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream("1".getBytes()));
   Console.main(new String[0]);
  } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
   org.junit.Assert.fail("Unexpected InputMismatchException");
  }
 }
}`