# How to have the console support input for System.in in Idea unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea

When unit testing in IntelliJ IDEA Education Edition, the console does not support System.in input.

The code I wrote is as follows:

```java
@Test
void main() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int judge = 1;
    while (judge == 1)
    {
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("输入的数为：" + n);
        if (n == 0)
            judge = 0;
    }
}
```

When I run the test, I cannot enter it from the console and show that the test passed. I knew that unit tests didn't need input from the console to complete the test, but I happened to find out about the problem and wondered how to fix it. Just start learning unit tests, teach us a lot!

Comment: "When unit testing in IntelliJ IDEA Education Edition, the console does not support System.in input" - Is that definitely true?  That does not sound right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JUnit: How to simulate System.in testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647907/junit-how-to-simulate-system-in-testing)

Comment: Normally tests are supposed to be automatic and do not expect input from console. Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148698#comment=27-2257633 for a way to workaround this but please also note that there are side effects.

Answer (score 0):

When doing unittest you have two components: The **unittest** itself and the **code under test** (cut).

Your example looks like as if you try to build a unittest by simply adding the `@Test` annotation to the tested code. This does not work.

As a start you should create a class containing you *production code* (the cut) and another class with the same name appended with `Test`:

```
class ProductionCode {
  // something to test
}
```

and

```
class ProductionCodeTest {
  // the tests for the production code
}
```

The responsibility of the `*Test` class is to set up a *test environment* for the cut. In your case this involves to replace any *dependencies* (as `System.in` or the `Scanner` object wrapping it and `System.out`) with *test doubles*. The best way to do this it to use a *mocking framework* like `Mockito`:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ProductionCodeTest {
   @Mock 
   private Scanner input;
   @Mock 
   private PrintWriter output;
   
   private ProductionCode cut;

   @BeforeEach
   void setup(){
      cut = new ProductionCode(input,output);
   }
}
```

But this raises the problem that you need a possibility to replace the real dependency in your cut. This is done preferably via *constructor injection:

```
class ProductionCode {
   private final Scanner scanner;
   private final PrintWriter output;
   ProductionCode(Scanner scanner, PrintWriter output){
     this.scanner = scanner;
     this.output = output;
   }

   void main(){
     int judge = 1;
     while (judge == 1)
     {
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        output.println("输入的数为：" + n);
        if (n == 0)
            judge = 0;
     }
   }
}
```

Now you can verify the expected behavior of your cut which is the *return value* (which you don't have) and/or communication with its dependencies, which is the methods called and parameters passed:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ProductionCodeTest {
   @Mock 
   private Scanner input;
   @Mock 
   private PrintWriter output;
   private ProductionCode cut;

   @BeforeEach
   void setup(){
      cut = new ProductionCode(input,output);
   }

   @Test(name="returns when user entered '0'")
   void test(){
     // arrange / given
     Mockito.when(input.nextInt()).thenReturn(1,2,3,4,5,0);
     
     // act / when
     cut.main();

     // assert / then
     Mockito.verify(output, Mockito.times(6))
            .println(Mockito.anyString());
   }
}
```

#### Conclusion

Unittesting is more that just writing a random annotation to some code written. Your example became complex very quickly because you choose a rather hard to test scenario to start. I'd suggest a *pure function* like a method that adds two numbers and returns the result as a better starting point and deal with the dependency stuff later.