# JUnit Test - BufferedReader Input Redirection

Tags: java, junit, bufferedreader, io-redirection

I'm new to JUnit tests and I've written code to redirect a file as an input, but I'm not sure how to test it. What's the best way to test the code?

```
private static String request;

public static void main(String[] args) {
   readFile();
}

public static void readFile() {

    try {
       /* BufferedReader to read text from an input stream */
       BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

       /* While loop to read each line of the file. request - each line is a different client request */ 
       while ((request = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Client request: " + request);
       }

       /* Closes input */
       input.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JUnit: How to simulate System.in testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647907/junit-how-to-simulate-system-in-testing)

Answer (score 0):

`System.in` is a static field.
Here are some steps to test your class:

1. Create a mock PrintStream.
2. In a method annotated with `@BeforeAll`, save the current System.in value.
3. In a method annotated with `@BeforeAll`, set System.in to your mock.
4. In a method annotated with `@AfterAll`, set System.in to the saved value from line 2 above.