# Using java Log files and log4j

Tags: java, swing, log4j, logfiles

I am new to log files.
I want to log exceptions thrown while running the application and some other statements when a user uses my java swing application. 
Using logs I believe that some problems which I haven't been able to handle and find in my application can be identified and solved by looking at the logs. 

As I think, the best way to get such statements out of the application is creating log files. 
I read some articles and   found something called log4j.
Please any one let me know more about log files(advantages) and good sample codes in a swing application showing getting statements to an external file.

Comment: Start by reading this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727500/log4j-vs-system-out-println-logger-advantages then look here http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html and then here http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html Practically log4j is used almost the same way whether its Swing application or any other application.

Answer (score 2):

The main advantage of Log4j is that allow logging using different [levels](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html) and different output type([Appenders](http://www.allapplabs.com/log4j/log4j_appenders.htm)), the library is fully configurable with its log4j.properties where you can define its configuration.

Another advantage of log4j is that log files contain *semi structured information about application problems* and exists several applications to view and filter a log4j generated files.

Take a look [here](http://www.vaannila.com/log4j/log4j-file-appender-example-1.html) for a log4j configured with a File Appender example .