# In Spring-based web application, where is my console/log output going to?

Tags: spring, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I'm writing a simple Spring-based web application and deploying it to Websphere Liberty 8.5.5.9; I've gotten past my deployment problems and the application seems to start (according to the Liberty `console.log`).  However, I'm not seeing any console or log output.  My application main class, which contains print statements in the main method, is:

```
@Configuration
public class UserSettingApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    ServletContext servletContext;

    private static final LoggerUtils logger = new LoggerUtils( UserSettingApplication.class );

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        builder.sources(UserSettingApplication.class);
        return builder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.addListener(RequestContextListener.class);
        this.servletContext=servletContext;
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println( "Entering UserSettingApplication.main" );
        SpringApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder = new UserSettingApplication().configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder());
        applicationBuilder.run(args);
        System.out.println( "Entering UserSettingApplication.main" );
    }
    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext run(SpringApplication application) {
        WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = super.run(application);
        Environment env = webApplicationContext.getEnvironment();
        String sessionName = env.getProperty("server.session.cookie.name", "xplore-session-id");
        servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setName(sessionName);
        return webApplicationContext;
    }
    @Bean
    protected RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }
  @Bean
  public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    return args -> {

      logger.info("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

      String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
      Arrays.sort(beanNames);
      for (String beanName : beanNames) {
        logger.info(beanName);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Shouldn't I be seeing the print statements in the main method in the WASLiberty `console.log`?

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't I be seeing the print statements in the main method in the WASLiberty console.log?

You will not see any printouts from the `main` method as it is not executed in the Liberty. The `main` method is used for standalone apps started from the command line not run from the app server. Put your messages in the `configure` method like below and you will see it.

```
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        System.out.println("##############@@@@@@@@@@@@##############Starting app");
```

Answer (score -2):

System.out.println() will **NOT** write into **files** such as console.log.

Instead it will write into console such as commandline window or eclipse console.

You need to use **loggers** such as log4j or Java.util.logging for writing into files.

You can find more info here [**what-is-the-difference-between-java-logger-and-system-out-println**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869391/what-is-the-difference-between-java-logger-and-system-out-println)

Comment: I *thought* I've seen println output in .../<server>/logs/console.log in the past.   Also, I am writing to both stdout and to log files, so I'm still puzzled as to why I don't see my output.

Comment: This answer is not correct, all System.out.printlns go to the `message.log` in the Liberty and to the `console.log` if you started the server with the `run` command instead of `start`. So check your `message.log` file for these entries.

Comment: Downvoted because this is inaccurate and misleading. Please be aware you can delete your answer and get rep points back.

Comment: @NathanHughes, Thanks for teaching, I am here to learn and this answer is one of the mistakes. Sometimes points are less important than a reminder :-)