# How to test print that made by function?

Tags: junit, console, output

I have a function which should print string.
I want to test through JUnit Is really the function printing what it is supposed to print.
How to do it?

for example, this my function:

```
public static void test(int a){
    System.out.println(a + "^2=" + (a*a));
}
```

and I want to check that for a = 3 is printing `3^2=9`

Ps, I can not change the function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JUnit test for System.out.println()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119385/junit-test-for-system-out-println)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this.Hope it will work for you.

```
public void TestPrint {
    @Rule
    public final StandardOutputStreamLog log = new StandardOutputStreamLog();

    @Test
    public static void test(int a) {
        System.out.print(a + "^2=" + (a*a));
        assertEquals("3^2=9", log.getLog());
    }
}
```

Comment: First off, thank you! Secondly, When I try to use an object StandardOutputStreamLog as proposed, costing me an error "StandardOutputStreamLog cannot be resolved to a type"