# How to test a print method in Java using Junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I have written a method that is printing output to a console. How should I test it?

```
public class PrinterForConsole implements Printer<Item>{

   public void printResult(List<Item> items) {
        for (Item item: items){
            System.out.println("Name: " + item.getName());
            System.out.println("Number: " + item.getNumber());

            }
        }
}
```

currently, my test looks like this

```
public class TestPrinter{
    @Test
    public void printResultTest() throws Exception {
            (am figuring out what to put here)

        }
}
```

I have read the solution at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119385/junit-test-for-system-out-println) (thanks @Codebender and @KDM for highlighting this) but don't quite understand it. How does the solution there test the print(List items) method? Hence, asking it afresh here.

Comment: You might look into [JMockit](http://jmockit.org), which I think would allow you to mock `System.out.println`.  However, I haven't tried specifically mocking this method.  I've seen it used for other methods in `System`, but here you're using `out` which is a static field.  There should be a way, though.

Comment: You don't really say *why* you don't understand the answer for the question this duplicates.

Comment: Ok, the reason why I don't understand the answer is because I was trying to test a method I created while the answers there seemed to test what the JVM already has test cases for.

Answer (score 20):

Since you have put you don't get what the duplicate question says, I will try to explain a little.

When you do, `System.setOut(OutputStream)`, whatever the application writes to the console (using `System.out.printX()`) statements, instead get written to the `outputStream` you pass.

So, you can do something like,

```
public void printTest() throws Exception {
      ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));

      // After this all System.out.println() statements will come to outContent stream.

     // So, you can normally call,
     print(items); // I will assume items is already initialized properly.

     //Now you have to validate the output. Let's say items had 1 element.
     // With name as FirstElement and number as 1.
     String expectedOutput  = "Name: FirstElement\nNumber: 1" // Notice the \n for new line.

     // Do the actual assertion.
     assertEquals(expectedOutput, outContent.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The best way to test it is by refactoring it to accept a `PrintStream` as a parameter and you can pass another `PrintStream` constructed out of `ByteArrayOutputStream` and check what is printed into the baos.

Otherwise, you can use `System.setOut` to set your standard output to another stream. You can verify what is written into it after the method returns.

A simplified version with comments is below:

```
@Test
public void printTest() throws Exception {
    // Create our test list of items
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    items.add(new Item("KDM", 1810));
    items.add(new Item("Roy", 2010));

    // Keep current System.out with us
    PrintStream oldOut = System.out;

    // Create a ByteArrayOutputStream so that we can get the output
    // from the call to print
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // Change System.out to point out to our stream
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(baos));

    print(items);

    // Reset the System.out
    System.setOut(oldOut);

    // Our baos has the content from the print statement
    String output = new String(baos.toByteArray());

    // Add some assertions out output
    assertTrue(output.contains("Name: KDM"));
    assertTrue(output.contains("Name: Roy"));

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Note that if the `print` method throws an exception, the `System.out` is not reset. It is better to use `setup` and `teardown` methods to set and reset this.

Comment: thanks, @KDM, could you provide a sample?

Comment: I flagged it as duplicate. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119385/junit-test-for-system-out-println

Comment: yup, i read this post before asking here, I don't quite get that post as I'm unable to relate it to how to test my method (please see last line in my post)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this.

```
@Test
    public void printTest() throws Exception {
        OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(os);
        objectInTest.print(items);
        String actualOutput = os.toString("UTF-8");
        assertEquals(expectedOutput, actualOutput);
    }
```

Comment: thanks Jose, i see where you're going, how do I get the objectInTest from my printTest() method?

Comment: Your post did not have the name of the class being tested nor the constructor so I didnt include it.  Without seeing the constructor and class name I don't know how to instantiate an instance of your class being tested.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Simple Test Code :-

```
@Test
public void out() {
System.out.print("hello");
assertEquals("helloworld", outContent.toString());
}
@Test
public void err() {
System.err.print("helloworld 1 ");
assertEquals("helloworld 1", errContent.toString());
}
```

For more :[JUnit test for System.out.println()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119385/junit-test-for-system-out-println)

Comment: thanks, shldn't my test case be testing the 'print(List<Item> items)' method?

Comment: i'm actually testing a custom print method i wrote, not java's print method. Does that change how you would test printing to console?

Comment: If you believe the question is already answered somewhere else, flag it as duplicate instead of copy-pasting the ansewer (which doesn't even make sense in this case and lacks context)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, what I came up with is this (after going through all the answers and links to possible duplicates above).

```
import org.junit.Test;
@Test
public void shouldPrintToConsole() throws Exception {
        Item testItem = new Item("Name", "Number");
        List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(testItem);

        Printer print = new Printer();
        printer.printOutput(items);
    }
```

Read up on naming convention (shouldPrintToConsole()) for testing too. Wondering if this is the convention because I see many sites that follow and many that don't.