# How to write junit for this method:

Tags: java, junit

```
public void declareWinner()
        {
         compare and declare winner 
            if(getLive_player1()==0 && getLive_player2()>0)
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 wins with "+getLive_player2()+" cells alive.");
            }
            else if(getLive_player2()==0 && getLive_player1()>0)
            {
                System.out.println("Player 1 wins with "+getLive_player1()+" cells alive.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("There is a tie.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JUnit test for System.out.println()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119385/junit-test-for-system-out-println)

Comment: don't see how this is unclear?

Comment: Himanshu, suggest you separate the logic that returns a particular string into a method returning `String` - and then unit test that (much easier than messing with streams)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's clear that you have a handful of different branches in your code, so you'll want to implement unit tests where you can hit your `if` and `else if` statements:

- `player1 = 0` and `player2 > 0`
- `player1 = 0` and `player1 > 0`

As well as a test where you hit your `else` statement:

- Clearly multiple options, but `player1 > 0` and `player2 > 0` will suffice to reach that branch.

So that's at least three different `@Test` methods.

I'm assuming your concern is determining how to capture the `System.out` calls. You can change the `out` stream to one which points to something that can be captured programmatically. That is achieved with [`System.setOut()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html):

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
  ByteArrayOutputStream myOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  System.setOut(new PrintStream(myOut));
  // do your setup and then execute declareWinner()...
  String methodOutput = myOut.toString();
  // Use Assert.assertEquals(...) to check methodOutput against expected value...
}
```

#### By the way

Based on what I can see, how do you know that two scores > 0 end in a tie? Seems like the `else` statement hasn't really closed out all of the options. But then again, I'm not sure what you're underlying code is doing...