# System.out.print doesn't output to console when running from Junit

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, junit4, system.out

When running:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print(".");
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }
}
```

vs. when running same code from junit:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print(".");
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }
}
```

There is different behaviour:
for the main() - the output is displayed as expected, as the process runs ("." -> ".." -> "...")

however, for JUnit, when running same piece of code, No output is displayed as the process runs - It's flushed only when quitting the test.

Why does this happen? Is there any way to workaround it if I need the status to be shown in console during the test run?

I need to print to the same line, so using println wouldn't suit.

Comment: with println it works but I need it without new line though...

Comment: Why? Junit tests should not need human interaction.

Comment: I think this has been asked and answered before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119385/junit-test-for-system-out-println

Comment: It works fine... I ran the same on Eclipse IDE. It is printing the dots on the same line for every 200ms. Please check on the IDE once.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many ways people run JUnit tests (from within an IDE, from within a build system like Maven, or from a command line that uses the JUnit library directly). It appears that the way that you're running it uses a standard output that doesn't flush on every output. (This is probably intentional, as often tests are run in a batch using a continuous integration system, and the logs reviewed afterward, so not flushing on every write can improve performance.)

But, if you need to flush the buffer explicitly, try using [`System.out.flush();`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#flush--) after each `.print` call.

Another option, depending on what you're actually looking to do, may be to use a more full-featured logging system than the built-in System.out stream.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that seems to be the reason, but explicit use of System.out.flush(); after each .print(".") doesn't display the output either (when running from within intelliJ IDE). println(".") on the other hand does display the output...

Comment: I am also having this problem when running with ant

Answer (score 0):

This still doesn't work in IntelliJ 2019. *sigh*

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print(".");
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }
}
```

To achieve somewhat what you are looking for I had to force a newline periodically like this:

```
@Before
public void forceConsoleOutput()
{
    new Thread( () -> {
        for ( ; ; )
        {
            // Does nothing. Why JetBrains?
            // System.out.flush();

            System.out.println();
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep( 5000 );
            }
            catch ( InterruptedException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } )
    {{
        start();
        System.out.println( "Terminated" ); // The threads naturally stop between method tests
    }};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use a logger of your choice. Used `log4j` to printout on console.
Import below dependence on `pom.xml`

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

In the JUnitTestClass import

`import org.apache.log4j.Logger;`

Then declare log

`public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(JUnitTest.class.getName());`

to printout
`log.info("....");`

Hope this works for your case.

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl + Shift + p and type show test output. Alternatively you can open the output window (Ctrl + J) and choose to see Test Output from a combo box on it's right upper corner.

Comment: Please exlain further. Which IDE are you talking about? I use Android Studio and these keybindings did not work for me

Answer (score -1):

Create your logs using `System.out.println()` instead. I know that's not the best solution but worked for me.