# set number of withdraws to 3 and test it in Junit Testing.

Tags: java, junit, set

In a Saving account for the withdraw variables i need to make sure it can't withdraw more than 3 in a month. I checked the criteria in the setter but I'm not sure how to do the testing in the JUintTesting. As both of them are void method and the testing method returns a boolean i am getting a error of void below is my code.

```
public void setNumberWithdrawals(int w)
{

    if (getNumberWithdrawals() > 3)
    {
        System.out.println("You already have more than 3 withdraw!!");
    }
    else
    {
        numberWithdrawals = w;
    }
}
```

For JUNit testing

```
SavingsAccount sa1;

 @Test
public void testsetNumberWithdrawals()
{
    assertEquals(true, sa1.setTest(4));
}
```

I am expecting it to return false since i pass 4 but i keep on getting the void and return type expected error, i even tried assigning the value to another int variable for number and tested it but i still got the error.

Comment: you have to initialize `SavingsAccount` instance before setting value

`SavingsAccount sa1 = new SavingsAccount();` Let me know, if that worked

Comment: i did create a instance  

      @Before
        public void setup()
       {
        sa1 = new SavingsAccount("Name",1234,50,.02,20);
       }
    
It still wont let me do it, thank you

Comment: Can you show all the code, please? i.e, setTest but maybe [JUnit test for System.out.println()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119385/junit-test-for-system-out-println) can help

Comment: i have to agree with @aimee. As a suggestion try to use AssertTrue/AssertFalse like this:  `@Test public void test() { sa1.setTest(4); assertFalse(true,sa1.getTest());`

Comment: commit your code to github and share a link

Comment: https://github.com/timilsina123/java1/projects

i dont know if i did it right but here is the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption: You're using JUnit 4 (seems like a safe assumption given that the code you provided is using the @Test annotation).

You would want something like this for your test class:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SavingsAccountTest {

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream errContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @Before
    public void setUpStreams() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent));
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUpStreams() {
        System.setOut(null);
        System.setErr(null);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        SavingsAccount savingsAcct = new SavingsAccount(...);
        savingsAcct.setNumberWithdrawals(...);
        assertEquals("You already have more than 3 withdraw!!\r\n", outContent.toString());
    }

}
```

**Other thoughts:**

Given the code you posted in your question and code on github some things seem a little strange. It might just be that some of the code is still missing, but I want to point out a few things that stand out:

You posted this code: 
`assertEquals(true, sa1.setTest(4));`

Now according to what I read on github, `sa1` is an instance of `SavingsAccount` yet I don't see a definition for this `setTest(...)` method anywhere. I do see this `SavingsAccount extends Account` so I suppose `setTest(...)` could be defined in the `Account` class. The reason this stands out is that you said you were trying to test `SavingsAccount.setNumberWithdrawals(...)` but you're not invoking `setNumberWithdrawals` in your test. Again, I suppose that this `setTest` method could indirectly invoke `setNumberWithdrawals` but that's not clear from everything you posted.

You said in your question:

> make sure it can't withdraw more than 3

The logic you have is `if (getNumberWithdrawals() > 3)` which means the number of withdrawals will have to be more than 3 to trigger this logic. This seems to violate your requirement.

Comment: I think you need to study the following topics: [How to write methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) - especially the return type of methods; and [data types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). Hopefully if you study these two topics you will understand why `assertEquals(3,sa)` does not make any sense. What this says is that you expect the `SavingsAccount` object be equal to the integer 3.

Comment: Similarly when you write this `assertEquals(true,sa.setNumberWithdrawals());` you are saying that `setNumberWithdrawals()` is going to return a boolean value of true. Unless `setNumberWithdrawals()` has a return type of boolean this will never work.

Comment: Thank you i was kinda a able to do what i needed too but as this line "assertEquals(4,sa.getNumberWithdrawals());"  is true i get the true along with you already have 3 withdraw. I need it to some how throw the error i tried to pass the set in sa.set but it wont let me do that. 

 public void testSetNumberWithdrawals()
    {
        SavingsAccount sa = new SavingsAccount("Name", 1234,50, 0.2,4);
        sa.setNumberWithdrawals(4);
        assertEquals(4,sa.getNumberWithdrawals());
    }

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it makes more sense to why the set wont work. I will dig into it some more.

Comment: The issue with `getNumberWithdrawals` returning 4 and getting "already have 3" at the same time is a logic bug. The method `setNumberWithdrawals` has a parameter `w` but the logic inside the method does not check the parameter when printing the error message: `if (getNumberWithdrawals() > 3)` does not use `w`. When you call `SavingsAccount(...4)` the method `getNumberWithdrawals` returns a value less than or equal to 3 which allows number of withdrawals to be set to 4. Then when you call `setNumberWithdrawals` it triggers the error message since `getNumberWithdrawals` will return 4

Comment: perfect thank you, i understood my whole loop criteria was not checking what i wanted it to do it, thank you