# Post event from native android to react native

Tags: android, android-fragments, react-native

I have a scenario where I have a fragment inside an activity (extending AppCompatActivity). Now from this fragment I need to post an event that I can listen to in my react-native code

> Fragment.class

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    ......

    public void onBookingCompleted(boolean success) {
       if (success) {
           sendEventToReact(); // <--- function i used to send event to my react native code
       }
    }

   private void sendEventToReact() {
    ReactApplicationContext context = (ReactApplicationContext) getContext();
    context.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
            .emit("YouCustomEventName", null);
   }

}
```

Now the problem is, I cannot convert my **`context`** to **`ReactApplicationContext`**

I already had a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40932026/5575410), but I want to know if there is any way I can post this event from a fragment inside an activity which is **`NOT`** extending **`ReactActivity`**

> Also is there a way where I can pass an event from my fragment to my
>   native module which can further pass this to react-native?

Comment: Is the activity holding this fragment extends `ReactActivity`?

Comment: No the activity holding this fragment extends AppCompatActivity.