# JUunit assertion error on overriding system.out.println

Tags: java, junit, assert

I followed the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119385/junit-test-for-system-out-println) to override the `System.out.println` call in java.

this is the program

```
public class palstr
{
    public String rev(String a)
    {
        String b=new StringBuffer(a).reverse().toString();
        return b;
    }
    public int check(String a,String b)
    {
        if(a.equals(b))
        {
                    return 1;
        }
        else
        {
                    return 0;
        }
    }

   public static void main(String a){
     palstr obj = new palstr();
     String b = obj.rev(a);
     int check= obj.check(a, b);

     if(check == 1){
       System.out.println("palindrome");
     } else {
       System.out.println("not palindrome");
     } 
   }
}
```

and this is the testcase

```
import java.io.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class palstrTest
{
    @Test
    public void mainTest(){
        System.out.println("madam is a palindrome string");
        ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
        palstr.main("madam");
        assertEquals("palindrome", outContent);
    }
 }
```

when i am running the test i am getting the following error

```
.madam is a palindrome string
E
Time: 0.026
There was 1 failure:
1) mainTest(palstrTest)
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<palindrome> but was:<palindrome
>
```

Comment: Well `outContent` is a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, not a `String`. Those two are different things - it sounds like you should convert the contents of the `ByteArrayOutputStream` into a string and then compare those...

Comment: As you saw when doing what my answer suggested, the types you try to compare mismatch -> do what Jon said.