# Testing System.out.println not working but System,out.print using JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am learning unit testing with JUnit in Netbeans. But I know how the JUnit works and how to test the System.out.print -
 [JUnit test for System.out.println()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119385/junit-test-for-system-out-println). I am a very new to JUnit because I just started JUnit today.

This is my test class

```
public class CDTest {
    CD cd;
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream errContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    public CDTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {


        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        System.setOut(null);
        System.setErr(null);
    }   



    @Test
    public void testSystemOutPrint(){
        System.out.print("hello");
        System.out.print("hello again");//Please pay attention here. Just System.out.print()
        assertEquals("hellohello again", outContent.toString());
    }

}
```

When I run the test, it is working successfully. Now I am only testing to the System.out.print. But when I test System.out.println() as below

```
@Test
public void testSystemOutPrint(){
    System.out.print("hello");
    System.out.println("hello again"); //Please pay attention here for println()
    assertEquals("hellohello again", outContent.toString());
}
```

The above code give me this error.

[image]

I tried adding system to fix the error like this.

```
@Test
public void testSystemOutPrint(){
    System.out.print("hello");
    System.out.println("hello again"); //Please pay attention here for println()
    assertEquals("hellohello again ", outContent.toString());//Please pay attention to the space after "again"
}
```

As you can see above, I added a space after "again". It is still giving me the error when I run. I tried this too

```
assertEquals("hellohello again\n", outContent.toString());
```

How can I test System.out.println instead of System.out.print?

Comment: What is the difference between `print` and `println`? -> `println` appends a *newline* character at the end. That's `\n`.

Comment: It is not the space, it is the \n character (new line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
String expected = "hellohello again " + System.getProperty("line.separator");
assertEquals(expected, outContent.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println` prints a new line. Change: `"hellohello again"` to

```
"hellohello again" + System.lineSeparator()
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run this, but I suspect `System.out.println` is adding a linebreak to the end of `"hellohello again"`. So your strict equals is probably failing for that.

You may want to consider either changing your assertion to

```
assertTrue(outContent.toString().startsWith("hellohello again"));
```

Or add a line break to the end of your expected String. That might be tricky because it will change depending on the system running your tests. So you might need something like `System.getProperty("line.separator");` or a similar solution to getting the correct line break character at runtime.