# Testing a simple hello world method

Tags: java

I have worked with junit test integration tests and controller tests in spring and usually we test the output of a method but when i tried to test a simple hello world in main method i had no idea how to go about it so will like to get any idea on what do write

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

This is the simple java class any idea how i can test it
I tried to write something like this

```
public void mainMethodTest() throws Exception{

        System.out.println("hello world");
        String[] args = null;


        Assert.assertEquals(System.out.println("hello world"),App.main(args));
    }
```

Comment: `System.out` prints to standard output - in order to capture that you'll need to start a new process (see `Runtime.exec`) and see what gets printed on the standard output. Do that, and you'll have tested if `System.out` works :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119385/junit-test-for-system-out-println

Answer (score 6):

You could assign to the `System.out` variable a `ByteArrayOutputStream` object which you store the reference in a variable.
Then invoke your `main()` method and assert that the `String` content of the `ByteArrayOutputStream` object contains the expected `String`:

```
@Test
public void main() throws Exception{                
    PrintStream originalOut = System.out; // to have a way to undo the binding with your `ByteArrayOutputStream` 
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(bos));
    // action
    App.main(null);
    // assertion
    Assert.assertEquals("hello world", bos.toString());
    // undo the binding in System
    System.setOut(originalOut);
}
```

**Why does it work ?**

`bos.toString()` returns the `"Hello World!"` `String` passed in the method under test:

```
System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
```

as after setting `System.out` in this way :  `System.setOut(new PrintStream(bos));`, the `out` variable refers to a `PrintStream` object that decorates the `ByteArrayOutputStream` object referenced by the `bos` variable.
So any `System.out` invocations will write `byte`s in the `ByteArrayOutputStream` object.

Comment: `setOut` requires a `PrintStream`, see my answer for details.

Comment: @Lothar Indeed. Thanks :) Writing without compiler creates this kind of issue :)

Comment: i have only  <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

Comment: it doesnt allow for Annotation @Test

Comment: If `assertEquals` fails your will introduce side effect in your test by leaving `System.out.println` pointing to custom stream.

Comment: The `@Test` annotation is included since JUnit 4. You use it. So it should work. Just add the import : `import org.junit.Test`

Comment: in the assert method i dont get how bos.string has a string hello world in it

Comment: @tsolakp It is right. Doing it in a `finally` statement or a `@Before` method is preferable.

Comment: wow thats deep , where can i learn about such deep knowledge of java any reference books or something ? thats great thanks @davidxxx thanks

Comment: @valik I edited to explain why it works. By reading it carefully and by testing yourself with a debugger in your IDE, you should get it I am sure

Comment: @valik Simple experience coming from working with a language. Sooner or later you come up with problems like these you spend time on solving. After a couple of years you end up with a stack of knowledge you collected over time.

Answer (score 5):

You can change your class this way

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class TestHelloWorld {
    
    public final static void main(String[] args) {
        doPrint(System.out);
    }
    
    static void doPrint(PrintStream ps) {
        ps.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

and test the `doPrint` function by providing your own `PrintStream` you create around a `ByteArrayOutputStream`:

```
public void mainMethodTest() throws Exception{
    ByteArrayOutputStream data = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(data, true, "UTF-8");
    TestHelloWorld.doPrint(ps);
    ps.flush();
    Assert.assertEquals("Hello World" + System.getProperty("line.separator"), new String(data, "UTF-8"));
}
```

Another solution is to replace the system's `PrintStream` by your own:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(data, true, "UTF-8"));
```

but that's quite ugly and I try to avoid that. Above solution is more clear, easier to maintenance and you can be sure that no other part of a larger application is printing something to STDOUT while you do your test, leading to a failure of it.

Comment: Make the code more naturally testable is a good thing. You have my vote :)

Answer (score 1):

You can run Junit from a main method if thats what you mean.

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore(); 
    Result result = null;
    try {        
         result = junit.run(MyTestClass.class);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int passed = result.getRunCount()-result.getFailureCount();
}

public class MyTestClass{
    @Test
    public void testAllBrowsers(){
         //test code and asserts
    }
}
```