# PowerMock: How to spy System.out.println?

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class MyClass { 
    public MyClass(){
    }
    public void hello() {
       System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

and I want to test 'hello' method:

```
@Test
public void testHello() {
    MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    mc.hello();
}
```

Now, I want to spy System.out.println and make sure that this method was called with "hello" as argument. How do I do it?

Comment: Can you please write the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JUnit test for System.out.println()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119385/junit-test-for-system-out-println)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out` is actually an instance of `PrintStream`, so my approach would be to create a mock of this class and direct output to that using the [`System.setOut`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-) method:

```
PrintStream outMock = Mockito.mock(PrintStream.class);
System.setOut(outMock);
System.out.println("Hello");
Mockito.verify(outMock).println("Hello");
```

Remember to restore the previous `PrintStream` instance after the test, preferably in a `finally` clause.