# Trying to use Junit to verify console output matches a string

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to use Junit to verify that something output by a method matches a string using assertequals, but I can't get it to work. Because it says that the test case is undefined for (String, Void) My code for the method is below

```
public void speciesInformation() {
     switch (species){ 

     case"Penguin":System.out.println("Penguin Trivia fact");
     break;

     default: System.out.println("There is no current information for that species");
     break;
     }       
}
```

and the junit code I'm attempting to use is(other tests omitted):

```
public class AnimalsTest extends junit.framework.TestCase{
public void testSpeciesInfo() {   
    assertEquals(" Penguin Trivia fact/n", penguin.speciesInformation());
}
}
```

All my other tests work because they're based on a return, but this one is supposed to be based on what's printed by the public void method and I can't tell how to do it or find information on how.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ByteArrayOutputStream` for this, set `new PrintStream` of `byteArrayOutputStream` in `System.setOut`, then you can assert what was logged in console easily.

[See this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119385/junit-test-for-system-out-println)

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's not always easy to assert some things, especially if they are static methods.

In this case, you can set another `Stream` for the `System.out`, what is explained in another answer.

However, if we talk about testing in general, you should ask yourself: "What do I really need to test?" Actually, you probably want to test that correct string was printed, right? So:

1. Was at least something printed?
2. Was the string that was printed the expected string?

You can check the second one using the tool you've already mentioned - asserting correctness of a method, returning a string. To do this, you can refactor your method a bit:

```
public void speciesInformation() {
  System.out.println(getSpeciesInforationText(species));
}

public void getSpeciesInforationText(String species) {
     switch (species){ 

     case"Penguin":
         return "Penguin Trivia fact");

     default: 
         return "There is no current information for that species");
     } 
}
```

This way you can easily test the `getSpeciesInforationText` correctness.

And the first method becomes very simple - you just call `print` method there. As a result you can either not test it all (because it's very simple) or you can use a technique called Mocking to test that you called the method. But it will require much more actions from your side. If you are interested in it, check out what `Mockito` is and how to use it.