# How to test code that uses readline (System.`in`) in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, junit5, system.in, junit-jupiter

How do I test code in kotlin that does a readline like below:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*
import java.io.*
fun foo() {
    val string="a b\nc d"
    var bais: ByteArrayInputStream=string.byteInputStream()
    val bis=BufferedInputStream(bais)
    //var l=bis.readLine() // no readline!
    // program uses just readline()
    var br: BufferedReader =BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(bais))
    var l=br.readLine()
    println(l) // works file
    val si=System.`in`
    println("System.`in` is ${si::class.simpleName}") // says it's a BufferedInputStream
}
fun main() {
    foo()
}
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS) internal class T1KtTestCase {
    @Test fun testFoo() {
        // ?
    }
}
```

Comment: you are using java framework, in kotlin testing of `System` methods doesn't differ from java. check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119385/junit-test-for-system-out-println

Comment: yes. looks like i am hosed as i need to mock readLine()

Answer (score 2):

You may add `inputStream` and `outputStream` as arguments to your function `foo`:

```
fun foo(inputStream: InputStream, outputStream: OutputStream) {
    val name = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream)).readLine()
    PrintStream(outputStream).println("Hello, ${name.trim()}!")
}

fun main() {
    foo(System.`in`, System.out)
}
```

And then you can test your `foo` function as follows:

```
class Test {

    @Test
    fun testFoo() {
        val inputStream = "username".byteInputStream()
        val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        foo(inputStream, outputStream)
        assertEquals(String(outputStream.toByteArray()), "Hello, username!\n")
    }

}
```

Comment: yes, but how do you test a piece of code that has a readLine() in it and uses system.in?

Comment: I've edited my answer, now I use `readLine()` method to read input. You cannot test `System.in` or it is too difficult to do. Ask yourself what you want to test. In my example it would be better to have separate `fun sayHello(name: String) { return "Hello $name" }` and test only that function. That's the point of unit testing, you should test small parts of your program.

Comment: kotlin has some extension functions to make this more readable. You can use `inputStream.reader().buffered()` and `"string".reader().buffered()` for example. I think if OPs function is dealing with strings he should use a `Reader` or `BufferedReader` though, rather than the raw `InputStream`.