# How to write Junit test for this java code?

Tags: java

So my problem is that i need to write a junit test for this code and I'm not able to. What the code does is, depending on the input it will give a grade.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grade{

    static void getNumericGrade(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter numeric grade: ");
        double numGrade = input.nextDouble();
        String letterGrade;
        /**
         *  Method creation to convert numeric grade or GPA to letter grade
         * @param numGrade is GPA
         */

        if (numGrade > 4.00 || numGrade < 0) {
            letterGrade = "N";
        }
        else if (numGrade >= 3.85 && numGrade <= 4.0 )
        {
            letterGrade = "A+";
        }
        else if (numGrade >= 3.5 && numGrade < 3.85 )
        {
            letterGrade = "A";
        }
        else if (numGrade  >= 3.333 && numGrade < 3.5 )
        {
            letterGrade = "A-";
        }
        else if (numGrade >= 3.0 && numGrade < 3.333 )
        {
            letterGrade = "B+";
        }
        else if (numGrade >= 2.667 && numGrade < 3.0 )
        {
            letterGrade = "B";
        }
        else if (numGrade >= 2.333 && numGrade < 2.667 )
        {
            letterGrade = "B-";
        }
        else if (numGrade >= 2.0 && numGrade < 2.333 )
        {
            letterGrade = "C+";
        }
        else if (numGrade >= 1.667 && numGrade < 2.0 )
        {
            letterGrade = "C";
        }
        else if (numGrade >= 1.333 && numGrade < 1.667 )
        {
            letterGrade = "C-";
        }
        else if (numGrade >= 1.0 && numGrade < 1.333 )
        {
            letterGrade = "D+";
        }
        else if (numGrade  > 0 && numGrade < 1.0 )
        {
            letterGrade = "D";
        }
        else        {
            letterGrade = "F";
        }

        if (letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
            System.out.println(numGrade + " is not a valid grade" + letterGrade);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Your grade is "  +  letterGrade);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /**
         * Prints letter grade from GPA
         * @return letterGrade
         */
        getNumericGrade();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to change the source code of `getNumericGrade()`?

Comment: Why do you have javadocs *inside* the method? They are supposed to be "above" the method.

Comment: State what you mean by "not able to". Are you unable to think of a test for this code or do you need a guide on [how to get started with junit](https://www.javatpoint.com/junit-tutorial)?

Comment: yes i can change the getNumericGrade()

Comment: I am unable to think of test for this code and need some help to make one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function `getNumericGrade()` to take a parameter instead of reading the input from the scanner, as well as to return the output instead of printing it on console:

```
static String getNumericGrade(double numGrade) {
    double numGrade = input.nextDouble();
    String letterGrade;
    /**
     *  Method creation to convert numeric grade or GPA to letter grade
     * @param numGrade is GPA
     */

    if (numGrade > 4.00 || numGrade < 0) {
        letterGrade = "N";
    }
    ...
    return letterGrade;
}
```

Change your `main` so that it's in there that you get the input from the scanner and print it on the screen:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter numeric grade: ");
double numGrade = input.nextDouble();
String letterName = getNumericGrade(numGrade);
if (letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){

    System.out.println(numGrade + " is not a valid grade" + letterGrade);
}
else{
    System.out.println("Your grade is "  +  letterGrade);
}
```

... and then test the method containing the logic easily like this:

```
@Test
public void exampleTest() {
    double testInput = 4.5;
    String grade = Grade.getNumericGrade(testInput); 
    assertEquals("expected grade", grade);
}

//more test with more inputs
```

Note: since the function really takes a double and returns a String all the time, you can probably write a single unit test and parametrize it.

You can check [parameterized tests (available from Junit5)](https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5)

Answer (score 1):

Check this excellent article [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-testing-system-out-println) about testing `Println()` or even better the accepted answer here: [JUnit test for System.out.println()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119385/junit-test-for-system-out-println)

I would go another way though. I would rewrite the function

```
    static string getNumericGrade(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter numeric grade: ");
        double numGrade = input.nextDouble();
        String letterGrade;
        /**
         *  Method creation to convert numeric grade or GPA to letter grade
         * @param numGrade is GPA
         */

        if (numGrade > 4.00 || numGrade < 0) {
            letterGrade = "N";
        }
        else if (numGrade >= 3.85 && numGrade <= 4.0 )
        {
            letterGrade = "A+";
        }
        else if (numGrade >= 3.5 && numGrade < 3.85 )
        {
            letterGrade = "A";
        }
        else if (numGrade  >= 3.333 && numGrade < 3.5 )
        {
            letterGrade = "A-";
        }
        else if (numGrade >= 3.0 && numGrade < 3.333 )
        {
            letterGrade = "B+";
        }
        else if (numGrade >= 2.667 && numGrade < 3.0 )
        {
            letterGrade = "B";
        }
        else if (numGrade >= 2.333 && numGrade < 2.667 )
        {
            letterGrade = "B-";
        }
        else if (numGrade >= 2.0 && numGrade < 2.333 )
        {
            letterGrade = "C+";
        }
        else if (numGrade >= 1.667 && numGrade < 2.0 )
        {
            letterGrade = "C";
        }
        else if (numGrade >= 1.333 && numGrade < 1.667 )
        {
            letterGrade = "C-";
        }
        else if (numGrade >= 1.0 && numGrade < 1.333 )
        {
            letterGrade = "D+";
        }
        else if (numGrade  > 0 && numGrade < 1.0 )
        {
            letterGrade = "D";
        }
        else        {
            letterGrade = "F";
        }

        if (letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){

            return numGrade + " is not a valid grade" + letterGrade;
        }
        else{
            return "Your grade is "  +  letterGrade;

        }
    }
```

And then assert the text. You could even return the grade or -1 for non-grade and handle accordingly.

Also note that you should seldom declare functions as static in an OOP world, but that is a topic for another thread.